# Concat with short inpoint and outpoint differences leads to long still image in the final video

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I create a `list.txt` with `inpoint` and `outpoint` markers, that are sometimes close - down to 0.5s in difference with GoPro MP4-files.

Then I use `-y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -af aresample=async=1 -pix_fmt yuv420p "filename.mp4"`.

What happens is that the smaller the differences between `inpoint` and `outpoint` are, the longer a still image of the first video image is shown. Recently I had a 60 seconds long video and 30 seconds of it at the beginning were just the same image.

How do I need to change my command?

Comment: From the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) on `inpoint`: "This directive works best with intra frame codecs, because for non-intra frame ones you will usually get extra packets before the actual In point and the decoded content will most likely contain frames before In point too." And `outpoint`: "Out point therefore the decoded content will most likely contain frames after Out point too. If your streams are not tightly interleaved you may not get all the packets from all streams before Out point and you may only will be able to decode the earliest stream until Out point."

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Can you put that into plain english?